# Under Chisel 3, it takes 10 min to compile the Verilator generated C++ of Rocket Chip. Are there any ways to speed this up?

Tags: riscv, chisel

We are modifying Rocket Chip code.  After each modification, we need to run the assembly programs, to be sure everything still runs correctly.

To do this, the steps are:
1) Run Chisel, to generate Verilog
2) Run the verilog through Verilator, to generate C++
3) Compile generated C++ 
4) Run tests

Step 3 is about 10 times longer than it was under Chisel 2.  It takes about 10 minutes, which slows development.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Are you using the `--output-split-cfuncs` argument? If you're using the Makefiles in rocket-chip/emulator then you probably are but if not, it speeds things up a bunch: See https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/pull/818

Comment: Thanks, we gave this a shot, but unfortunately it didn't seem to have much effect.. was probably already enabled as we use the Makefiles in rocket-chip/emulator, as you noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a non-trivial amount of build and run time is spent on not-really-synthesizable constructs that are used for verification support.

For example, I disable the TLMonitors through the `Config` options. You can find an example in the `subsystem` Configs.

```
class WithoutTLMonitors extends Config ((site, here, up) => {
  case MonitorsEnabled => false
})
```